# Unable to insert collection in mongo database: Can't find a codec

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, codec

Mongo runtime throws following error when trying to insert a new document in the collection. Note that the database and collection does NOT exist yet (and my assumption is that mongo runtime will create the database, followed by collection and then insert my first document by converting my POJO to BSON using a default codec). Any suggestions?

**Error: 2015-12-13 18:46:46,384 - application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - [error] - application - Can't find a codec for class models.User.**

/* Model Class */

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.mongojack.ObjectId;

public class User {
  @ObjectId @Id public String _id;

  public String firstname;
  public String lastname;
  public String email;
  public String phone;
  public String address;
}
```

/* Controller Class */

```
public class Users extends Controller {

  @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
  public Result create() {
    Logger.info("Enter - Users::create()");
    try {
      Form<User> user = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
      if (user.hasErrors()) {
        Logger.info("User: " + user.toString());
        Logger.info(user.errorsAsJson().toString());
        return badRequest(user.errorsAsJson());
      }
      else {
        User oneUser = user.get();
        MongoClient mongoClient= new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("marketplace");
        MongoCollection<User> col = db.getCollection("users", User.class);
        col.insertOne(oneUser);
        mongoClient.close();
        return ok();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      return internalServerError(e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally {
      Logger.info("Exit - Users::create()");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to wrap the MongoCollection with a JacksonDBCollection to enable all the MongoJack features.

Something like this:

```
JacksonDBCollection<User, String> userColl = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(col, User.class, String.class);
```

And then use userColl to insert your new object.

It seems that this the only way supported at this time. This requires using the getDB() method, which is deprecated since the mongo driver 3.0. 
See the relevant issue on github here:
https://github.com/mongojack/mongojack/issues/105

Comment: do you have suggestions on my question below on adopting MongoCollection?

Answer (score 0):

Yup - this works. However I had to use deprecated getDB since it has a getter that returns collection of type DBCollection which "wrap" function expects. I was hoping to use getDatabase instead but gets me MongoCollection which Jackson's "Wrap" won't accept. Any suggestions?

```
User oneUser = user.get();
MongoClient mongoClient= new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("marketplace");
DBCollection col = db.getCollection("marketplace");
JacksonDBCollection<User, String> userCol = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(col,User.class, String.class);
userCol.insert(oneUser);
```